# `sudo make install` sends files to an unexpected location

Tags: command-line, compiling

I'm trying to install vtk7.1. I have successfully built from source and I'm having trouble with `sudo make install`.

From the command line, I see files are installing in `/usr/local/.....`, for example:

```
Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/Modules/vtkRenderingGL2PS.cmake.
```

However I can only find this file at `/usr/local/natives-Linux-x86_64/cmake/vtk-7.1/Modules/vtkRenderingGL2PS`.

My questions is:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I make the files install in `/usr/local` instead of `/usr/local/native-Linux-x86_64`?

Comment: Has the command finished successfully or is there any error message?

Comment: Hi Melebius, thanks for the fast reply.
The only notable/questionable command line output are:
1. After the line `Package VTK for Java - natives-Linux-x86_64`, there are severals warnings in form of `/usr/local/natives-Linux-x86_64/./{file name} : no such file or directory`. I've checked that those files exists.
2.  For some files, after the line `-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/vtkpython` the path is set to NULL: `-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/vtkpython" to ""`. I don't know if this is expected.

Comment: I’d recommend contacting the project developers. The actions done by `make` are determined by the `Makefile` of the particular project.